# How do I get the URL of an HTTP redirect's target?

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine, redirect

I am writing client-side Python unit tests to verify whether the HTTP 302 redirects on my Google App Engine site are pointing to the right pages. So far, I have been calling `urllib2.urlopen(my_url).geturl()`. However, I have encountered 2 issues:

1. the URL returned by geturl() does not appear to include URL query strings like `?k1=v1&k2=v2`; how can I see these? (I need to check whether I correctly passed along the visitor's original URL query string to the redirect page.)
2. `geturl()` shows the final URL after any additional redirects. I just care about the first redirect (the one from my site); I am agnostic to anything after that. For example, let's assume my site is `example.com`. If a user requests `http://www.example.com/somepath/?q=foo`, I might want to redirect them to `http://www.anothersite.com?q=foo`. That other site might do another redirect to `http://subdomain.anothersite.com?q=foo`, which I can't control or predict. How can I make sure my redirect is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supply `follow_redirects=False` to the [fetch function](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction.html), then retrieve the location of the first redirect from the 'location' header in the response, like so:

```
response = urlfetch.fetch(your_url, follow_redirects=False)
location = response.headers['Location']
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. Although Alex's response was very good, this is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Use [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html?highlight=httplib#module-httplib) (and look at the return status and Location header of the response) to avoid the "auto-follow redirects" that's impeding your testing.  There's a good example [here](http://diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html).