# How can I determine the final URL after redirection using python / urllib2?

Tags: python, redirect, urllib2

I need to get the final URL after redirection in python.

What's a good way to do that?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353689/how-do-i-get-the-url-of-an-http-redirects-target

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> var = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.stackoverflow.com/')
>>> var.geturl()
'http://stackoverflow.com/'
```